# Is there a way to add support for HLS in desktop Chrome/HTML5 player?

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming

Desktop Chrome and FF do not support HLS. I know there is a plugin available to add HLS support to flash. Is there such plugin or technique available to enhance HTML5 on browsers which dont have HLS support yet?

Comment: So this question got downvoted because it doesn't show any research. I would like to add that I tried finding an answer to this a lot before posting it here. I discussed it with some people in the streaming industry and someone mentioned it maybe possible to create a plugin for html5 videoplayer to add hls support. I didn't find anything that supports this notion, hence I posted here to ask the community if this is possible.

Comment: I think your question got down-voted because it's too broad and you're requesting off-site resources. Both are considered off-topic on stackoverflow. Unless they involve programming, streaming question are pretty much off-topic everywhere except probably the general computing Q&A.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Not only it is possible, but it's been done numerous times. There are several open and closed source solutions available. A quick github search gave me this one.

https://github.com/RReverser/mpegts

EDIT: New/better option just released
http://engineering.dailymotion.com/introducing-hls-js/

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. It is what I was looking for.