# Dailymotion 360 video iframe - 403 forbidden and no supported source found

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, dailymotion-api

When I play 360 video embedded on our site using Android Chrome I get

```
GET http://www.dailymotion.com/cdn/manifest/video/x4xqjra.m3u8?auth=xxxxxx

f5eccb3….dmp.js:21 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

GET http://www.dailymotion.com/cdn/manifest/video/x4xqjra.m3u8?auth=xxxxxx&include=240 403 (Forbidden)
```

But playing same video on dailymotion.com works, which means either I implemented player API in wrong way or there is some CORS problem. I encountered similar problem on http://www.dailymotion.com/player so it may be iframe related (but I was able to play /player video at least once)

This is javascript creating player iframe on our site:

```
player = DM.player(document.getElementById("player"), {
            video: currentItem.dmc_id,
            params: {
                'autoplay': false,
                'ui-start_screen_info': false,
                'endscreen-enable': false,
                'ui-highlight': '#4182d3'
            }
        });
```

There are no problems on desktop Chrome.

Comment: See [How can I precisely detect HLS support on different browsers and different OS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039076/how-can-i-precisely-detect-hls-support-on-different-browsers-and-different-os)

Comment: but why am I able to play it directly on dailymotion site?

Comment: See [hls.js](https://github.com/dailymotion/hls.js/tree/master)