# Extract metadata from audio m3u stream with javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to get the live track title and artist from this audio stream:
http://icy1.abacast.com/agmedia28-kkalfmaac-48.m3u

When I search google everyone says that an m3u file is just a playlist but that does not seem to be the case here.

I know that the live data is there because it shows up in VLC.

I am using [ionic-audio](https://github.com/arielfaur/ionic-audio) to play the stream but any data about the track is what I set, I think this will need to be done separately.

Comment: See [How can I precisely detect HLS support on different browsers and different OS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40039076/how-can-i-precisely-detect-hls-support-on-different-browsers-and-different-os/)

Comment: Save the m3u file to disk, then open with a text editor. You'll see it only contains an url. VLC shows the title and artist, because it can extract it from the stream. To do it yourself you'll have to extract the meta serverside, extract from the stream server, or use a 3rd party api... see http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=icecast+meta